# Having troubles with inputing std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, input, compiler-errors

Im having some troubles using std::array.

I have an array called b, lets declare it like this: `array<int,2>b[3];`

Perhaps I would input it in a way like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
    int a; cin >> a;
    b[i] = {a,i};
}
```

When I do this though, I get an error:

```
ar.cpp:30:8: error: expected expression
                b[i]={a, i};
```

Also lets say I want to input an vector<array<>>, lets define it as `vector<array<int, 2>> ans;`

I would probably do this:

```
int a = 10, b = 20;
ans.push_back({a,b});
```

I received another error stating :

```
 error: expected expression
  ans.push_back({a, j});
```

*Note* I put them as separate cases and separate variables

I tried doing methods like make_pair but that didn't work.

These errors are probably because I use c++17 and not 11. But I've tried for a very long time and I wasn't able to fix it. To help me fix this please go here: [Visual Studio Code c++11 extension warning and lamda warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62756568/visual-studio-code-c11-extension-warning-and-lamda-warnings)

Can anyone suggest what I should do instead of this? Thank you.

*Note* perhaps a method similar to make_pair but for vector<array<>> is what im looking for? When I inputed vector of pairs I always used push_back and make_pair instead of {} or emplace_back because those methods didn't work because I always received errors like those.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 when people input vector of pairs most people do: a.push_back({b,c}) but i've had this problem for a while and instead of {} I always had to write "make_pair" because I received that error. Do you know how I can replace this make_pair in this case?

Comment: Why am I receiving down votes?

Comment: Hmm, for me it works fine

Comment: I have no idea what `b[i] = {a,i};` suppose to do. It doesn't have a seance. IMO it should be just `b[i] = a;`

Comment: I'm guessing this is the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62812376/difficulty-changing-c17-to-c11-on-vscode?noredirect=1 ?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes

Answer (score 0):

In std::array, the first template argument specifهes type of array. If you want to map an integer to another , you probably need to use std::map:

```
std::map<int, int> a;
a[3] = 10;

std::cout << a[3] << std::endl;
```