# Difficulty changing c++17 to c++11 on Vscode

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

Few months ago I tried compiling c++11. I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53995830/compiling-c11-in-visual-studio-code)
but then I received these following errors:

```
error: 
      function-like macro '__GLIBC_PREREQ' is not defined
#if __GLIBC_PREREQ(2,15) && defined(_GNU_SOURCE)
    ^
In file included from wdq.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/bits/stdc++.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cuchar:53:11: fatal error: 
      'uchar.h' file not found
 #include <uchar.h>
```

I've constantly tried over and over again but im at the point im about to give up because im constantly wasting my time with this.

I tried re writing files but more errors kept on coming and coming so I desperately need help with this.

If someone can help me fix this issue that would be incredibly helpful to me:)

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for? I can't see any specific programming question. Are you looking for a paid freelancer to convert your project from C++17 to C++11?

Comment: You probably need to use `clang++` rather than `g++` as you're using a Mac. Might need to stop using the non standard `bits/c++` that I've seen in your other questions too. Please also provide a [mre] with the code you're trying to compile and how you're compiling it

Comment: @AlanBirtles Ok, I will try downloading a clang and I will let you know. I dont understand how im suppose to provide a minimal reproducible example because these are just issues with my computer.

Comment: @AlanBirtles THANK YOU SO MUCH. I just solved the problem. I cant thank you enough. I used <bits/stdc++.h>  which is what caused all of my problems. THANK YOU SO MUCH! I've been struggling so much for a month and I can't thank you enough.

Comment: `<bits/stdc++.h>` is a non-standard gcc/libstdc++ header, you are using xcode which defaults to clang/libc++ so its not surprising it doesn't work